# How do i make this work? Mixing up concepts as a beginner

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, try-catch

I mixed up a lot of concepts in this code. I basically was trying to create a simple console app, but i got lost along the way.

First of all i just wanna understand these concepts better, so i tried them like a wild teenager in a candystore. Im learning mostly alone so please dont get instantly mad at me, i have no mentor or anyone to coach me.

Heres the code, i know there is probably a lot wrong here.
Can you call another function like that with a break statement? I guess not but im trying to learn.

I probably mixed up some bad coding practice and want to get rid of it before i get used to bad habits. I can make to reach some blocks but for all the wrong reasons.

```
def calculator():
    print("Welcome to the NA/EU temperature converter project")

    while True:
        try:
            ques = input("""
What do you want to convert?\n
> Fahrenheit to Celsius -> Press 1.
> Celsius to Fahrenheit -> Press 2. 
> """)

            if ques == 1:
                celsius()
                break

            if ques == 2:
                fahrenheit()
                break



            else:
                 break
        except ValueError:
            print("You typed in the wrong thing.")


def celsius():
    fahrenheit = int(input("Enter Fahrenheit: "))
    print("Celsius >")
    print((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9)
    exit()


def fahrenheit():
    celsius = int(input("Enter Celsius: "))
    print("Fahrenheit >")
    print((celsius * 9 / 5) + 32)
    exit()


calculator()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would adjust it a bit:

```
def calculator():
    print("Welcome to the NA/EU temperature converter project")

    while True:
        try:
            ques = input("""
What do you want to convert?\n
> Fahrenheit to Celsius -> Press 1.
> Celsius to Fahrenheit -> Press 2. 
> exit -> Press anything else.
> """)

            if ques == '1':
                celsius()
            elif ques == '2':
                fahrenheit()
            else:
                exit()
        except ValueError:
            print("You typed in the wrong thing.")


def celsius():
    fahrenheit = int(input("Enter Fahrenheit: "))
    print(f"Celsius > {(fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9}")


def fahrenheit():
    celsius = int(input("Enter Celsius: "))
    print(f"Fahrenheit > {(celsius * 9 / 5) + 32}")


calculator()
```

The program runs as long as I enter 1 or 2. If I enter anything else (eg Enter), then the program ends.